# Web View working in only a few versions of Lollipop

Tags: android, webview

i am working on web view,but the web view is opening in only lollipop 5.1 version and it is not opening in other versions of lollipop and in higher versions of android.I also gave all permissions in the manifest file.any help would be appreciated.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.colorssoftware.sdfg">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
        <user-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
        <permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
            android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
            android:protectionLevel="normal" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.low_latency" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.pro" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true"/>
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="true" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.PermissionRequest" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MICROPHONE" />


        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

this is main activity

```
package com.colorssoftware.sdfg;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.net.http.SslCertificate;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView htmlWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        htmlWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSetting = htmlWebView.getSettings();
        webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSetting.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSetting.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSetting.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSetting.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSetting.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        /*webSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);*/
        webSetting.setAllowFileAccess(true);
       /* webSetting.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSetting.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
       */ htmlWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        htmlWebView.requestFocus();
        htmlWebView.loadUrl("https://www.colourssoftware.com:3443/\n");

        htmlWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            // Need to accept permissions to use the camera
            @RequiresApi(api= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP )

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                Log.d("hhhhhh","onPermissionRequest");
                request.grant(request.getResources());
            }

        });
    }


    public static Certificate getCertificateForRawResource(int resourceId, Context context) {
        CertificateFactory cf = null;
        Certificate ca = null;
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        InputStream caInput = resources.openRawResource(resourceId);

        try {
            cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509","BC");
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
        } catch (java.security.cert.CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                caInput.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "exception", e);
            }
        }

        return ca;
    }

    public static Certificate convertSSLCertificateToCertificate(SslCertificate sslCertificate) {
        CertificateFactory cf = null;
        Certificate certificate = null;
        Bundle bundle = sslCertificate.saveState(sslCertificate);
        byte[] bytes = bundle.getByteArray("x509-certificate");

        if (bytes != null) {
            try {
                CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509","BC");
                Certificate cert = certFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
                certificate = cert;
            } catch (java.security.cert.CertificateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return certificate;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
           view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            SslCertificate sslCertificateServer = error.getCertificate();
            Certificate pinnedCert = getCertificateForRawResource(R.raw.fullchain, MainActivity.this);
            Certificate serverCert = convertSSLCertificateToCertificate(sslCertificateServer);

            if(pinnedCert.equals(serverCert)) {
                handler.proceed();
            } else {
                super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question. Please delete the screenshots and post *the text* of your [mcve]. And, please explain **in detail** what "is not working" means and and "for all versions" means.

Comment: what is the problem? What exactly is not working? By default, you can use WebView on any Android version.

Comment: web view is opening in lollipop 5.1 version but not in anyother versions of lollipop and above versions of android